# Wrong number of arguments with SQL ISNULL() on Access DB

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have this query in VB application on Access DB:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT Specialization, MAX(a.faultZone) AS faultZone, ISNULL(a.faultCount, 0) AS NoOfFaults  FROM Technicians AS t 
    LEFT JOIN 
             ( 
            SELECT DISTINCT Faults.[Type] AS faultType, MAX(Faults.[Zone]) AS faultZone, COUNT(Faults.[Type]) AS faultCount 
            FROM Faults "
            WHERE Faults.[Zone] = 8 " ' this value will be from variable
            GROUP BY Faults.[Type] "
            ) AS a 
    ON (t.Specialization = a.faultType) 
    WHERE t.specialization <> 'None' "
    GROUP BY a.faultCount, t.Specialization
```

It gives following problem that I can't solve...

> "Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression
>   'ISNULL(a.faultCount, 0'."

What I want to achieve is simply set value of `NoOFFaults` to zero, which would mean there are no faults in particular Zone.

Thank You

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to add my two cents, and while I like the simple syntax of Nz(), if you seek trouble free performance, both IsNull() and NZ() should be avoided in favor of Is Null:
  `IIF(a.faultCount Is Null, 0, a.faultCount)`.

See the excellent explanation here: http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html

Also, if your tables are in SQL Server or Oracle, using Nz() will force more of the query to be executed locally, with a HUGE performance impact.

Comment: +1 I like the link.  Personally I have never had trouble with Nz but it may be a problem in certain cases

Comment: Extremely I wish I could accept all answers here. I checked link and may rewrite my code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This just got me through much frustration. Very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft Access' version of `IsNull` is different than most SQL versions; it simply [returns TRUE if the value is NULL, and FALSE if it isn't](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/isnull-function-HA001228867.aspx).

You need to basically build your own using [`IIF()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx?CTT=1):

```
IIF(ISNULL(a.faultCount), 0, a.faultCount)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think that you are looking for the nz function

```
Nz(a.faultCount, 0)
```

will return 0 if the value is null

Comment: Yes, I just searched for this and it is also good answer. Thx

Comment: +! - Wow, somehow I've either never seen that, or completely forgotten about it.  I love how SQL Server's and Access' versions of `ISNULL` are completely different.