# Access SQL query with nulls and aggregate function

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

Tried to come up with SQL query in MS Access, but null values and an aggregate function have me stumped. Any help appreciated.

Query to show records from TABLE1 where the EditDate (which may be null) is greater than the maximum LastImportDate from TABLE2.

TABLE1

Field Name  -  Data Type
ReportID    -  Number 
EditDate    -  Date/Time

TABLE2

Field Name      -  Data Type
LastImportDate  -  Date/Time

Thank you.

Comment: Do `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` work in Access's SQL? And if the `EditDate` is `NULL`, do you want to ignore it? You could probably use something like `... where ISNULL(TABLE1.EditDate, '1970-01-01') > TABLE2.LastImportDate...`

Comment: Here's a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633980/wrong-number-of-arguments-with-sql-isnull-on-access-db) or working with `ISNULL` in MS Access. Something like this: `... where IIF(ISNULL(TABLE1.EditDate), '1970-01-01', TABLE1.EditDate) > TABLE2.LastImportDate...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE editDate > (
    SELECT max(lastImportDate)
    FROM   table2
)
```

not sure how exactly that translates to an access query, but that is the idea.

Additionally, if you could break out the max date as a separate variable, that will get you a bit better performance - something like:

```
DECLARE @maxDate DATETIME
SET @maxDate = (
    SELECT max(lastImportDate)
    FROM   table2
)

SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE editDate > @maxDate
```

Lastly, if you wanted to dates that have a null editDate, you can have the query interpret nulls as some arbitrary date like isNull(editDate, '1900-01-01') - this will make null editDates get interpreted as 1900 Jan 1